# How to detect Landsat 1 MSS striping?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I'm working with historical Landsat-1 MSS tier 2 imagery in Google Earth Engine. A large portion of images in my collection have this striping distortion (below) that makes the data in all bands unusable.

I'm guessing that this level of striping is not fixable. **Is there then a programmatic way to detect / filter out images with these kinds of patterns?**

[image: Landsat 1 MSS image with striping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QA_PIXEL and QA_RADSAT bands](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LM01_C02_T1#bands) can be used to mask out much of the scan line issues. Many of those scan lines are identified in the QA_RADSAT band as saturated pixel; I include the QA_PIXEL for good measure. Once the bad scan lines are masked out, you can (for example) create multi-month composites. You could also query the QA_RADSAT band for the ratio of pixels that are considered saturated to those that are not, and then `.set()` the ratio as an image property and filter on it to remove images where the ratio of bad to good pixels is too high.

Here is an example of using the QA bands to mask images:

```js
// Masks MSS image using the QA_PIXEL and QA_RADSAT bands.
function applyQaMask(img) {
  var qaPixelMask = img.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var qaRadsatMask = img.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);
  var qaMask = qaPixelMask.multiply(qaRadsatMask).rename('QA_mask');
  return img.updateMask(qaMask);
}

// A point of interest for filtering images by region.
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.146, 44.479]);

// Get a Landsat 1 collection, filter to a region and date range.
var col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LM01/C02/T2')
  .filterBounds(geom)
  .filterDate('1976-07-01', '1976-09-01');

// Apply the QA mask.
var colMasked = col.map(applyQaMask);

// Define visualization settings.
var visParams = {bands: ['B7', 'B5', 'B4'], min: 20, max: 120};

// Show the original image and the masked version - notice that saturated
// scan lines are masked out in the QA masked version.
Map.setCenter(-120.4715, 45.1064, 11);
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(col.first()), visParams, 'Image');
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(colMasked.first()), visParams, 'Image w/ QA mask');
```